# How can i make the Html drop down list to go up instead of going down

Tags: html, forms

i want the html drop down list to open the opposite way thanks.

Comment: Why? Do you like to annoy your users? This can't be done with a simple html drop down list, you'll need javascript and probably your own div-magic.

Comment: Scroll the page up so that the drop-down list box is closer to the bottom of the screen. It will automatically go "up" because there isn't enough room for it to go down. Magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends entirely on the browser and operating system and you have no control over it.
You'll need to make your own fake select element lookalike if you have such specific needs.